# Understanding the difference between subplot and add_subplot (scatter) plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to understand why the following plots look so different

```
plt.subplot(projection='3d')
plt.scatter(position1[:,0], position1[:,1], position1[:,2], marker='.')
plt.scatter(position2[:,0], position2[:,1], position2[:,2], marker='.')
plt.show()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(position1[:,0], position1[:,1], position1[:,2], marker='.')
ax.scatter(position2[:,0], position2[:,1], position2[:,2], marker='.')
plt.show()
```

basically, I don't understand why I need to add a subplot if I just want one plot anyway. So intuitively I would use the first plot, but they don't give the same result?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is not between `plt.subplot` and `fig.add_subplot`.
It is rather that in the first case you use pyplot's scatter function `plt.scatter` and in the second case you use the `scatter` of the axes, `ax.scatter`.

`plt.scatter` is a 2D function. It will interprete its third argument as the size of the scatter points and draw a scatter in two dimensions. (You see that the z axis is not scaled at all.)

When using `ax.scatter`, `ax` is a 3D axes (`matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot`). Its `scatter` method is different from the 2D case, as it expects 3 arguments `x,y,z` as input.

Now you can use both, `plt.subplot` and `fig.add_subplot`, for a 3D plot, but you cannot use `plt.scatter` on any of them.
Instead you need to use  `ax.scatter` in both cases, making sure that the `matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot`'s `scatter` method is called.

- One option is to use `plt.gca()` to get the current axes (which is the 3D axes):

  ```
  plt.subplot(projection='3d')
  plt.gca().scatter(position1[:,0], position1[:,1], position1[:,2], marker='.')
  plt.gca().scatter(position2[:,0], position2[:,1], position2[:,2], marker='.')
  plt.show()
  ```
- You can also get the axes from the call to `plt.subplot()

  ```
  ax = plt.subplot(projection='3d')
  ax.scatter(position1[:,0], position1[:,1], position1[:,2], marker='.')
  ax.scatter(position2[:,0], position2[:,1], position2[:,2], marker='.')
  plt.show()
  ```
- Of course you may use the way you already found working,

  ```
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
  ax.scatter(position1[:,0], position1[:,1], position1[:,2], marker='.')
  ax.scatter(position2[:,0], position2[:,1], position2[:,2], marker='.')
  plt.show()
  ```
- Or you may use `plt.subplots` (mind the `s`) to get a figure and axes handle at the same time,

  ```
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d"))
  ax.scatter(position1[:,0], position1[:,1], position1[:,2], marker='.')
  ax.scatter(position2[:,0], position2[:,1], position2[:,2], marker='.')
  plt.show()
  ```

The result will be the same in all cases.